# What are some minhagim of Ukrainians and Romanians (from the turn on 20th century)?

Tags: minhagim

There’s a whole lot written about minhagei litvish, Galicia, Yekke, but I’m not finding anything specific to Ukrainian and Romanian (southeastern Yiddish group/ not Hassidish) why is that? Does anyone have any sources to point me to? Do they pretty much follow the same as litvish?

Thanks!

Comment: At the time you mention, most of them became chasidim...

Comment: That can’t be true. Many many came to the USA around that time and were not hassidim. This was a big part of the Jewish community in nyc during that tk

Comment: Don't you mix them up with Hungarians (like Transylvania)?

Comment: “ Ukrainian Yiddish was the basis for standard theatre Yiddish, while Lithuanian Yiddish was the basis of standard literary and academic Yiddish.” https://yivoencyclopedia.org/article.aspx/Language/Yiddish#id0eztae

Comment: It's really hard to generalize when dealing with such small towns that were suburbs of suburbs of big cities, but their tradition was Ashkenazi, which was slowly being turned Hassidic. So it was possible to have towns where all halacha was kept according to Ashkenazi law, such as wearing Tefilin on Chol HaMoed with a bracha, but at the same time the way they pronounced words and spoke Yiddish was much closer to Hassidic, not Litvishe since the Rebbeim were all Hassidic, even though the townsfolk didn't pick up on it that strongly.

Comment: Although it's hard to tell today, Muncaks was much less what we would call Hasidic than say Satmar. But at the same time, Satmar was having a definite influence from right over the border in Hungary. I would guess had the war not happened, the entire Ukraine would've become much more Hassidic within a short time, but that just a guess.

Comment: It may be more helpful to consider the customs and practices of geographic regions (Volhyn, Galicia, Carpathia, etc.). The Jews of those areas didn't identify cohesively under one national umbrella of "Ukrainian"

Comment: @user6591 Both Munkács and Szatmárnémeti were parts of (Austria-)Hungary. The poster should clarify what does she consider Ukrainian and Romanian customs.

Comment: Thanks! I’m specifically interested in customs of Jews from Iasi, Romania, Starokonstantinov /krasilov, Ukraine (I think they’re considered volhyn) and Odessa, Ukraine.

Comment: Actually I think Starokonstantinov and krasilov are in podolia

Comment: If you check [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%91), they claim that in the 19th century most of the Jews in Starokostiantyniv where Chernobyl or Sadigura chasidim...

Comment: @Kazi It's really hard to argue about the nationality of areas that changed so frequently, but certainly right before WWII Muncatch was part of CheckSolovakia while Satmar was in Hungary.

Comment: Ok. So most were chassidish in staro - but chassidim today are such a small fringe group. Most descendents of jews who came over from that area to the US at the turn of the century  are not Hasidic. I would also say the generation that came through Ellis island and the next gen after were also not like the Hasidim of today. What changed? Was chassidut different back then?

Comment: Your statement is not even true in the US (go to Williamsburg or Kiryas Yoel). You might have this misconception due to Lakewood or because the Modern Orthodoxy stemmed from R' Soloveitchik, who was Litvish, while Conservative and Reform congregations also used Ashkenazi practices as a base (consider R Lieberman).

Comment: What is not true about what I said? I live in nyc. I’m very familiar with Williamsburg and kriyas Yoel. And I stand by my word, Hassidim are very few in number even compared to just the orthodox community at large in nyc.  I’m 3rd generation NYer on my mom’s side and 3/4 great grandparents on that side come from Ukraine or Romanian. (The 4th came from Minsk, so litvish to my understanding). Many Jews that came from vohlyn, podolia and surrounding areas are not Hasidic right now and if their ancestors were, they weren’t for generations. So what happened?  assimilation with other Jews in the US?

Comment: See my previous comment, in the US the less religious were predominantly Ashkenazi. In Israel you have the opposite effect. As most religious Zionists were from Poland and Ukraine praying nusach Sefard, becoming non-Charedi means following their customs.

Answer (score 1):

I can't promise this is accurate, but someone once told me that Ukranian Jews used to have a custom of not having a Shalom Zachor on Friday night. If they had a baby boy they had a kiddush either the first Shabbos after birth, or the first Shabbos after the bris or the first Shabbos after the baby was 30 days old and called this this the Shalom Zachor.
I met an older gentleman once who actually was from Ukraine and he said that the old Ukrainian custom was to never cover your head with your tallis unless you had smicha but he said over time this custom faded away.

Comment: The latter custom you mention is actually the halachah, as brought by the Magen Avraham on O"Ch 8:2

Comment: Ain't no thing like "Ukrainian Jews." To have a meaningful answer, you should specify from which town or region of the current Ukraine your acquaintance was coming from.